# Change FormLayout alignment at runtime

Tags: java, swing, jgoodies, form-layout

Is there a way using JGoodies FormLayout to change the alignment of a component once it has been set?

for example,

```
CellConstraints cc = new CellCosntraints();
panel.add(component,cc.xy(1,1,CellConstraints.DEFAULT,CellConstraints.FILL));
```

If I want to change `component` to be have a row constraint of DEFAULT instead of FILL, is there a way to change it now that it has been set without removing and re-adding the component?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you can:

```
FormLayout l = new FormLayout();
...
l.setContraints(component, newconstraints);
```

then probably do a `revalidate()` on the container to update things.

Comment: Ah, I was thinking I wasn't going to use that because it takes a whole new cell constraints object. I'll just modify the current one and then reset it for that component. I'll give that a try shortly, thanks.

Comment: The code clones the constraint object, so that should be safe.  [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.jgoodies/forms/1.2.1/com/jgoodies/forms/layout/FormLayout.java#FormLayout.setConstraints%28java.awt.Component%2Ccom.jgoodies.forms.layout.CellConstraints%29)

Comment: Are you sure about that? I didn't think it actually cloned the object. But I still think this will work since you can reuse the cellconstraints object for multiple components.

Comment: I linked the source code which shows that it does clone() the constraints.

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways (@Jim +1 for correct direction)

1) fills available Dimension inside container without resize for container

```
revalidate() //covered validate()
repaint() // required in some cases for JLabel, JTextComponents, JScrollPane ...
```

2) fills available Dimension inside container with resize for container

```
pack();
```

[this code can help you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8743985/714968)

Comment: while true, it's unrelated to the question ;-)